# NullPointerException when using @Inject annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection, inject

I got this error even thought I @Inject Message object in MyClass.
I just try to learn it now how can I Inject an object.

Please help me, Thanks!

Here are my example.

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String [] arg){
        new MyClass().print();
    }

}
```

MyClass

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyClass {

    @Inject private Message message;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(message.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Message

```
public class Message {

    public String getMessage() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using a DI framework?

Comment: And if so, which one, and how are you using it?

Comment: What do you add to tell the DI framework that the parent class MyClass is under its control?

Comment: I just using javax from javaee-api.
Do I need some Framework like Spring?

Comment: @duffymo I don't think this is quite a duplicate of the question you've marked. The confusion is with DI, not with the presence of an NPE.

Comment: @BalázsFodor-Pap Yes, you'll need a framework. `javax.inject` just provides a standardized set of interfaces and annotations for specific frameworks to use. It is not a DI implementation itself.

Comment: All right, thank you all.
And which framework should i learn first?

Comment: I suggested two popular ones in my answer. The skills you'll learn from one are largely transferable to others, so I wouldn't stress too much about the specifics.

Comment: After the good answers i using [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation) and i can injecting the Message object . Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not got anything that I can see which would interpret or make use of the `@Inject` annotation. You'll need some kind of DI framework present that will actually do the dependency injection for you. Perhaps consider looking at the minimal examples for something like [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Motivation) or [Spring](https://spring.io/)?

If you analyze your current program, you're just declaring a field (which is defaulting to `null`), and never setting it to anything, hence the NPE.